# Inserting / editing Header/Footer using vba - extra Paragraph Character After Header and Footer from Quick Part Gallery

Tags: vba, ms-word

If I insert a header or footer from the quick part gallery, it usually adds a standalone paragraph character on the next line.

[image]

This is extremely annoying because it requires cleanup every time. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? A couple of the default headers from the quick parts gallery do not do this. The ones I've created myself do - for both header and footer.

I've currently got a VBA macro that adds all these headers and footers automatically to documents in a directory, but it doesn't do me much good when I have to go in and hit delete twice for every document anyway. I can find and replace the paragraph markers (^p^p) through the script (which only works in the header), but doing so strips the style from the header. I'd rather these just not be a part of the quick part if that's an option. They weren't there when I saved the part out.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, Charles. I'll take this over to Super User - but I'm also looking for programmatic solutions. The point of this is so that my VBA script can add the quick parts without the extra paragraph mark, any solution that gets me there I'm ok with.  As for the quick part, the marks were not included in the part before it was saved. I've tried removing them and resaving the quick parts multiple times. Most of the prebuilt Word ones also do this.

Comment: You were storing building blocks with the same name in more than one template. The normal template is a poor place to store them when you are planning on distributing. I recommend looking at the hierarchy of templates - which building block gets used. The macros I provide do address various locations. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#hierarchy

Comment: A building block in the attached template gets used first. -- If none of that name, one of that name in the normal template gets used.  -- If none of that name found in either of those locations, one in a global template. If building blocks of the same name are in multiple global templates, I believe the one in the global first loaded is used but I have not tested this last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the part about why the paragraph mark is showing up in [your question posted on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1656569/extra-paragraph-character-after-header-and-footer-from-quick-part-gallery). This response is to address using vba to insert a building block. Your vba, though, is not causing the extra paragraph mark. As stated in the response in Super User, that is due to the content of the building block.

If your vba (not shown) opens the header or footer area and pastes content, then a bug in Word would retain the original paragraph mark as an extra. If you are using it, though, through one of the processes shown below, it should not.

*A recorded macro will seldom do what you want, especially if you are sharing the template.*

### Writing a Macro

> To do this, you need to know:
>
> - The name of the building block
> - The name (and location) of the template that holds the building block unless the macro is in the same template
> - How to insert a macro.
>   See Installing Macros and Install/Employ VBA Procedures (Macros).
> - Building Block Name = "MyBB" (example in this macro, change to fit)
>
> Situation 1 and 1a have the Building Block and the macro in the same template.
> This simplifies coding because a macro can always tell
> the name and location of the template that holds it. That information
> is required to use a macro to insert a building block.

**Situation 1 - template holds both the building block and the macro**

> Here is the macro to insert that uniquely-named building block at the insertion point in the document:

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'  Will not work if there are multiple building blocks with the same name in the template! See below.
'
   Dim sBBName As String
   sBBName = "MyBB"
   On Error GoTo Oops
   Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks ' Thank you Timothy Rylatt!
   Application.Templates(ThisDocument.FullName).BuildingBlockEntries(sBBName).Insert _
      Where:=Selection.Range, _
      RichText:=True ' Insert MyBB Building Block
   Exit Sub ' We're done here
Oops: ' Didn't work - building block not there!
   MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block " & sBBName & " cannot be found in " & _
      ThisDocument.Name & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

> This and the following macro are both contained in a demonstration template that can be downloaded from my downloads page.

> **Situation 1a - template holding building blocks and macro in same template - multiple building blocks with the same name**

> In this situation, the previous macro would confuse Word and give                 unpredictable (to the user) results. In this case, the macro needs to
> know both the gallery and category of the building block. The
> following macro assumes that the building block is stored in the
> AutoText gallery and in the General category. You can find the name of
> the gallery and category using the Building Blocks Organizer. Category
> names are plain text. Galleries are referenced in vba as Building
> Block Types and use constants. You can find a list of the constants
> for the different galleries here.

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'
' Assumes that the Building Block is of the type AutoText (wdTypeAutoText) in Category "General"
' See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243303(v=office.12).aspx
'
' This is based in part upon contributions from Greg Maxey and Jay Freedman - any errors remain mine
' Written by Charles Kenyon February 2016
'
   Dim sBBName As String
   Dim sTempName As String
   Dim oBB As BuildingBlock
   sBBName = "MyBB" 'use the name of your building block instead of "MyBB"
   sTempName = ThisDocument.FullName ' puts name and full path of template in string variable
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks  ' thank you Timothy Rylatt
   Set oBB = Application.Templates(sTempName).BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeAutoText) _
      .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks(sBBName)
   If Err.Number = 0 Then
      oBB.Insert Selection.Range, True
   Else
      MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block '" & sBBName & "' cannot be found in " & _
         ThisDocument.Name & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
lbl_Exit:
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

> This and the preceding macro are both contained in a demonstration template that can be downloaded from my downloads page.

**Situation 2 - template holding building block is in Word Startup Folder and named MyBBTemplate.dotx**

> This template, for some reason, does not hold the macro, it is in a separate template. We know the name of the container template. The
> name of the template containing the macro does not matter for our
> purposes.

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'  Will not work if the Startup Folder is the root directory of a drive, i.e. C:\
'  For use with building block stored in a template loaded in the Word Startup Folder that does NOT hold this macro
'  Will not work if there are multiple building blocks with the same name in the template!
'
   Dim sBBName As String
   Dim sTemplateName as String
   Dim sStartupPath as String
   sBBName = "MyBB"
   sTemplateName="MyBBTemplate.dotx"
   sStartupPath = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdStartupPath)
   On Error GoTo Oops ' error handler
   Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks  ' thank you Timothy Rylatt
   Application.Templates(sStartupPath & "\" & sTemplateName).BuildingBlockEntries(sBBName) _
      .Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True ' Insert MyBB Building Block
   Exit Sub ' We're done here
Oops: ' Didn't work - building block not there!
   MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block " & sBBName & " cannot be found in " & _
      sTemplateName".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**Situation 3 - template holding building block is "Building Blocks.dotx" in the building blocks storage location**

> This template also does not hold the macro because templates in the building blocks folder do not contribute macros to Word even if
> they contain them. This macro incorporates code from Greg Maxey and
> Jay Freedman given in this thread. Building Blocks.dotx is the name of
> the template used, by default, to store custom building blocks other
> than AutoText. It is stored, by user, in a language-dependent,
> version-dependent folder. This macro is intended to retrieve the
> building block regardless of the language or version.

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'  Based on code by Greg Maxey and Jay Freedman
'  For use with building block stored in the default custom building blocks file "Building Blocks.dotx"
'  Will not work if there are multiple building blocks with the same name in the template!
'
   Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks ' in case building blocks not yet accessed
   Dim sBBName As String
   Dim sStartupPath as String
   Dim sTemplateName as String
   sBBName = "MyBB"
   sTemplateName="Building Blocks.dotx"
   sStartupPath = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdStartupPath)
   On Error GoTo Oops ' error handler
   Application.Templates(sStartupPath & "\" & sTemplateName).BuildingBlockEntries(sBBName) _
      .Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True ' Insert MyBB Building Block
   Exit Sub ' We're done here
Oops: ' Didn't work - building block not there!
   MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block " & sBBName & " cannot be found in " & _
      sTemplateName & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

The various code for inserting building blocks is from my page on [AutoText, Building Blocks and AutoFormat](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock).

This is copied almost verbatim from my [earlier answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66235138/word-vba-insert-a-table-of-contents-building-block/66245344#66245344). That answer was helpfully edited by [Timothy Rylatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5211752/timothy-rylatt).